# ASP.NET applicationSettings (Giving Me) Fits

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, application-settings

I've read all of the examples and I've yet to figure out how to get information out of the web.config file using `applicationSettings` (as opposed to `appSettings`). I have the following for my `configSections`:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="ExcelREST.FDAllUpAvailabilityTable.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Then, for `applicationSettings` I have:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <ExcelREST.FDAllUpAvailabilityTable.Settings>
        <setting name="RESTPageURI" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://team/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="WorkbookLocation" serializeAs="String">
            <value>/sites/tel/Shared Documents/FD Dashboard Reports.xlsx</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="ResourceLoction" serializeAs="String">
            <value>/model/Tables('FDAllUpAvailabilityTable')?$format=html&amp;Ranges('MonthParameter')={0}</value>
        </setting>
    </ExcelREST.FDAllUpAvailabilityTable.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Now, I suspect that I may be making an assumption that's not valid; namely, that the appropriate classes will be generated to access my configuration information by Visual Studio (2010). I've simplified the example in that I *really* want to have several `<section name="..." >` within `configSections`.

What (probably obvious) step am I missing here? (I'm coding in C# and this is an ASP.NET 4.0 MVC application.) I'm about ready to bag it and just go with the simplistic `appSettings`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Project / Properties / Settings tab and click on the blue link, you'll get a new Settings.settings file generated in the Properties folder for the project.

That file generates a Settings.cs file that contains strongly typed properties for the settings you define in the editor, and gets its values from an applicationSettings configuration section that you can include in any managed process's .config file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want to make a [custom configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) not a custom application settings element.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done the above correctly, you can just access your data via

```
string restPageUri = ExcelREST.FDAllUpAvailabilityTable.Settings.Default.RESTPageURI;

string workbookLocation= ExcelREST.FDAllUpAvailabilityTable.Settings.Default.WorkbookLocation;
```

However, it looks like you have created these entries by typing them directly into your web.config. If you do not have a ExcelREST.FDAllUpAvailabilityTable.Settings class in your project, then you have to create one. The best way to create one is to use the [Visual Studio settings wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx).